# C++ Problems with #include <anyfile.h> when trying to compile a gstreamer app

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, gstreamer

I didn't find anything like this when I searched for it. I'm trying to make a simple gstreamer app based on code I found in another stack overflow thread. Whenever I try to compile it by going to the directory with command prompt and entering `cl cppgstreamer.cc`. Initially, the only include was `#include <gstreamermm.h>`, which gives me

> cppgstreamer.cc(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gstreamermm.h
>   ': No such file or directory

Even when I put `cppgstreamer.cc` into the same directory as `gstreamermm.h`. I then tried changing the include to

```
#include "C:\Users\MY_NAME\Documents\gstreamer c++\gstreamermm-0.10.10.2\gstreamer\gstreamermm.h"
```

with MY_NAME being replaced by my name.

This seems to work, but then it tries to do the includes in the `gstreamermm.h`, and they are in `#include <file.h>` form, so I get another fatal error C1083,except this time with `init.h`, or when I changed that, `error.h`. And they have dependencies. Is there a way that I can get my compiler to like the `#include <file.h>` syntax? I really don't want to go through the file and change every `#include <file.h>` to `#include "file.h"`.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm new to C++, although I've worked with C in the past.
I am using Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611276/visual-studio-express-2010-include-path

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the directory containing `gstreamermm.h` to include path. I don't have visual c++ here to check, but it's in somewhere in project properties under C/C++ .

Comment: Ok, I tried editing it in the visual c++ instead of notepad ++, creating a console application, and then adding the path of the directory with gstreamermm.h into the include directories path variable. gstreamermm.h now shows up when I click external dependencies, but when I try "cl cppgstreamer.cpp" with either #include <gstreamermm.h> or #include "gstreamermm.h", I get the "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: "gstreamermm.h" No such file or directory". Is there a separate command for including external dependencies or an I just doing something wrong?

Comment: how about: `cl "/IC:\Users\MY_NAME\Documents\gstreamer c++\gstreamermm-0.10.10.2\gstreamer" cppgstreamer.cpp` or some such? full list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy(v=vs.80).aspx